# How to connect ms sql-server using jdbc?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a Tomcat 7 and javascript application in here. Now i add jsp wiht connection to MS SQL-Server R2 data base.
In jsp file i have:

```
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Connection conn= null;
String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=dd_ugra";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"sa", "123456");
```

After i download jdbc for SQL-Server from Microsoft site and copy `sqljdbc4.jar` into `tomcat\lib` folder but when i start application i get error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver
```

In another case i try to use:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

And get another error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=ugra
```

How to correctly connect to SQL-Server?

Comment: Add this Jar file in project Class Path. and lib folder of application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made mistake on connection string, it should be something like

```
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverA:1433;" +
         "databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;" +
         "failoverPartner=serverB";
```

in the 2nd case, you may take it as 'jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://'

And the JDBC jar should be exist in Web content/WEB-INF/

Comment: if You create a project named as 'demo' in Eclipse, you can find a folder under demo/webContent/web-inf/lib,  copy your JDBC jar in this folder, this will be added in your project classpath.